# Android time logger with millisecond precision and error estimation

Tags: android, timestamp, ntp

Short skippable intro:

I work at a rehabilitation hospital that's a couple kilometers from where I live. The hospital pays a bus service that picks the employees up at certain fixed locations. There's this bus driver, that picks us at 7:00. The guy is FREAKISHLY PUNCTUAL. I mean, this guy has to be in the tenth of a second order. The clock turns from 6:59 to 7:00 EXACTLY when he opens the bus door. And I was thinking of recording his punctuality for like 30 days and make a nice Excel spreadsheet for him. Error propagation and everything. He might even get a raise, who knows?

I'll make a simple app to save time in milliseconds, that seems easy enough, there're like half a dozen solutions for that here in Stackoverflow.

So, to the question:

I hit a button on a widget. It gets a time in ms. It saves it on a file (.txt, .csv, whatever)

How would you estimate the mean error of an NTP synchronized Android phone? What's the most precise and exact way to save a timestamp?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The red lights are synchronized in a town, hence the relative punctuality of vehicles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is that time is relative, in the Einstein kind of way :) So if your reference is an Android phone synchronized with NTP, what is the driver's time reference? What if synchronization or timing somehow gets off, delayed on your phone and you have the impression that he's late one day, when in fact he's precisely on time relative to his reference?

But for the sake of solving the problem i think you can start by assuming he has the same time reference with you: some place in a network. I don't know the details of Android synchronization via time protocols, but i do know i built a so called [Network Synchronization API](http://www.currentmillis.com). In your case i think my [Java API](http://currentmillis.com/api/CurrentTime.java) might be of help. It tries to make a request for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch and then reads the response. The feature is that it gives you a framework on which you can estimate your true time compared to the server's by trying to discard network lag.

One thing to bear in mind: the solution above makes a request to my site (a.k.a. GoDaddy servers) which is probably different than the network location Android phones sync with. Feel free to change the request location.

Second thing to bear in mind: this rabbit hole goes deep :) No measurement can be perfect. You can try to achieve human / reasonable precision but it can never be perfect (e.g. there are other unknowns: what if there's a lag in your Android CPU just as you press the button, or what if your own reaction takes a few milliseconds? The moment you press the button is not the same as the moment the doors actually open and my impression is they're at least a few millis apart)